# How do I move a circle in a smooth way with css transform?

Tags: jquery, translate

I have 2 divs like this.

```
<div id="myimage" style="background-image: url('myimage.png'); background-size: cover; width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
<div id="mycircle" style="border:2px solid red; height:100px; width:100px; border-radius:50%; -moz-border-radius:50%; -webkit-border-radius:50%"></div>
```

I want to move the circle over the image with my mouse. That works perfect.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myimage').on("mousemove", function(event) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var x = event.pageX - offset.left;
        var y = event.pageY - offset.top;
        $('#mycircle').css('transform', 'translate('+x+'px, '+y+'px)');
    });
});
```

The problem is that the circle lags. Can this be done in a better way so the circle moves smooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an improved fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsh9tzjq/

Most importantly:

You set the position of the circle by manipulating top/left css properties

```
 $('#mycircle').css({'top':y+'px', 'left':x+'px'});
```

and make the circle 'transparent' for mouse events.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This prevents the circle to accidentally capture mouse events causing a perceived lag.

Comment: It is amazing to see how a few lines of code can have such a profound impact on solving all the problems for someone. :) Stay safe and healthy!